# All TFS User and Status

Tags: tfs

I have created a webform that has a couple of controls on it.  One of those controls is a  Status Combobox, which needs to be populated with Status (Which has been shown in TFS Combobox same like that in my webform).  I am unable to find status collection object in TFS.

And, I also need to populate All users in a combobox on my form in the same manner.

Can anyone have any idea how to populte all TFS user in my web from Combobox
and Status Collection of WorkItem in Staus Combobox

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two places that a list of values can be defined.  It can be defined in a global list, or it can be defined in the work item's definition.  Assuming that what you're talking about in your question are the "State" and "AssignedTo" fields, the following code will iterate through those values.

Note - these can vary between work item types, so you will need to know two pieces of information before you make this call:

1. The team project that contains the work item.
2. The work item type you are working on

In this example, I'm using the first team project in the collection, and the relatively-generic "Task" work item type.  You will probably want to specify a specific project (`wis.Projects[]`), and a specific work item type (`WorkItemTypes[]`).

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://sw100429:8080"));

        WorkItemStore wis = coll.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

        var values = wis.Projects[0].WorkItemTypes["Task"].FieldDefinitions[CoreField.State].AllowedValues;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
        }
```

Similarly, you can do the same with the `AssignedTo` field:

```
        values = wis.Projects[0].WorkItemTypes["Task"].FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo].AllowedValues;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
        }
```